# Como redirecionar o usuário para as configurações de permissões do app IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic, mobile

Preciso redirecionar o usuário para as permissões de localização do app para que ele possa selecionar a opção "Tempo todo", já que ela não aparece no popUp.

Preciso pegar a localização dele enquanto o app estiver em segundo plano mas se a permissão estiver em "apenas durante o uso", a localização não funciona.

Estou fazendo em AngularJS e IONIC Capacitor

Tentei usar o plugin OpenNativeSettings mas ele só me permite ir as configurações do app

```
  permissaoLocalizacao(){
    this.permissions.checkPermission(this.permissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
      .then(async (rs)=>{
        if(!rs.hasPermission){
          const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
            header: 'Info',
            message: 'Habilite a permissão de localização para "O tempo todo"!',
            buttons: [{
              text: 'OK',
              handler: ()=>{
                this.nativeConfig.open('application_details')
              }
            }]
          });
          await alert.present();
        }
      })
  }
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para redirecionar o usuário para as configurações de permissão de localização do seu aplicativo, você pode utilizar o método this.diagnostic.requestRuntimePermission do plugin cordova-plugin-diagnostic. Este método irá solicitar a permissão de localização ao usuário e, caso ele ainda não tenha concedido essa permissão, será exibida uma caixa de diálogo solicitando que ele conceda a permissão.

Aqui está um exemplo de como utilizar o método requestRuntimePermission para solicitar a permissão de localização:

```
import { Diagnostic } from '@ionic-native/diagnostic/ngx';

constructor(private diagnostic: Diagnostic) {}

async solicitarPermissaoLocalizacao() {
  try {
    const resultado = await this.diagnostic.requestRuntimePermission(this.diagnostic.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (resultado === this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED) {
      console.log('Permissão de localização concedida');
      // A permissão foi concedida, você pode começar a usar a localização do usuário
    } else {
      console.log('Permissão de localização negada');
      // A permissão foi negada, você deve exibir uma mensagem informando ao usuário a importância da permissão para o seu aplicativo
    }
  } catch (erro) {
    console.error(erro);
  }
}
```

Observe que você também pode verificar se o usuário já concedeu a permissão de localização utilizando o método this.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled. Caso a localização do usuário esteja desativada, você pode solicitar que o usuário ative a localização usando o método this.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings.

Espero que isso ajude! Qualquer dúvida, sinta-se à vontade para perguntar.